# Grid 19c: Purpose of QUORUM FAILGROUP on shared NFS mountpoint when you already have an +OCRDG diskgroup

Tags: oracle-asm, quorum

I'm working somewhere now where every ASM diskgroup has been made with an extra disk under the QUORUM FAILGROUP option, and is built with the following pattern:

```
CREATE DISKGROUP stuffdg NORMAL REDUNDANCY
  FAILGROUP x DISK 'AFD:X' SIZE 30G
  FAILGROUP y DISK 'AFD:Y' SIZE 30G
  FAILGROUP z ...
  QUORUM FAILGROUP qrm DISK '/nfsmp/stuffdgdisk' SIZE 1G
  ATTRIBUTE ...;
```

But on all clusters they have over here, there's also a diskgroup whose sole purpose is to host OCR, voting files, ASM instance spfile etc. This diskgroup (let's call it +OCRDG...) is *also* built upon a similar shared drive visible at OS level (along with two regular ASM disks configured with AFD). Verifying this with CRSCTL QUERY CSS VOTEDISK you're shown the following:

```
##  STATE    File Universal Id                File Name Disk group
--  -----    -----------------                --------- ---------
 1. ONLINE   2b07d0a959d14fcbbf891f99e3bade87 (AFD:OCRDGD1) [VOTE]
 2. ONLINE   8943a8f2a8c64fc4bfaae430f45bc58d (AFD:OCRDGD2) [VOTE]
 3. ONLINE   1f166e30237a4f54bfabeb8d0ed63786 (/nfsmp/ocrdgd3) [VOTE]
Located 3 voting disk(s).
```

Listing all files under /nfsmp shows that since their creation, *only* /nfsmp/ocrdgd3 is used, all other files (like stuffdgdisk above) have kept the timestamp of their creation, months ago.

My question: I've never used this configuration before (explicitly adding a quorum failgroup in regular diskgroups - I mean those used for data and archived logs destination or FRA), and obviously these files under /nfsmp (except for that which is used for OCR) are not used, so what is the point of this QUORUM FAILGROUP clause?? I've found the documentation very little helpful to understand this setup. Can someone enlighten me please?
Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 0):

A NORMAL redundancy ASM diskgroup used for voting disks requires 3 voting disks in 3 separate failgroups.

If you have only 2 regular failgroups, a quorum failgroup can be used for the 3rd voting disk. This is the only purpose of a quorum failgroup, it does not store any user data.

[Storing Voting Files on Oracle ASM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cwadd/managing-oracle-cluster-registry-and-voting-files.html#GUID-7680E1EB-C91F-4B32-82B8-80AC5D57D13C)

> A quorum failure group is a special type of failure group that is used
> to store the Oracle Clusterware voting files. The quorum failure group
> is used to ensure that a quorum of the specified failure groups are
> available. When Oracle ASM mounts a disk group that contains Oracle
> Clusterware files, the quorum failure group is used to determine if
> the disk group can be mounted if there is a loss of one or more
> failure groups. Disks in the quorum failure group do not contain user
> data, therefore a quorum failure group is not considered when
> determining redundancy requirements in respect to storing user data.
>
> ...
>
> - Normal redundancy: ...
>
> For Oracle Clusterware files, a normal redundancy disk group requires
> a minimum of three disk devices (two of the three disks are used by
> failure groups and all three disks are used by the quorum failure
> group) and provides three voting files and one OCR and mirror of the
> OCR. When using a normal redundancy disk group, the cluster can remain
> functional after the loss of one failure group.

Comment: Hey Balazs, thanks for your reply  - but I already read this documentation (otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question), but I'm afraid it does not answer my question: adding a quorum failgroup with a shared OS device, *what does it bring about* really?
As I said OS timestamps of these quorum disks in /nfsmp have not changed for months (except that one part of +OCRDG): are they *really used*? If yes - what do they contain??